# Configure Prometheus to use non-default port

Tags: http, port, systemd, prometheus

I would like to install Prometheus on port 8080 instead of 9090 (its normal  default). To this end I have edited `/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service` to contain this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus.yaml --web.enable-admin-api \
  --web.listen-address=":8080"
```

I.e., I am using option `--web.listen-address` to specifiy the non-default port.

However, when I start Prometheus (2.0 beta) with `systemctl start prometheus` I receive this error message:

```
parse external URL "": invalid external URL "http://<myhost>:8080\"/"
```

So how can I configure Prometheus such that I can reach its web UI at `http://<myhost>:8080/` (instead of `http://<myhost>:9090`)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The quotes were superfluous. This line will work:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus.yaml --web.enable-admin-api \
  --web.listen-address=:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.02. It requires:

```
--web.listen-address=:8080  #defaults to  IPv6
--web.listen-address=*:8080 # does not work
--web.listen-address=192.168.1.X:8080 # for IPv4
```

Comment: does config file really not have option for this? I can't believe it.

Comment: look into /etc/default/prometheus @quant2016

Answer (score 0):

There is a default config location for prometheus & prometheus-node-exporter.

Both support `--web.listen-address=host:port` in their respective config files in `/etc/default/prometheus` and `/etc/default/prometheus-node-exporter`

It is noteworthy that prometheus & node-exporter will prefer to bind to an ipv6 (if ipv6 interface is present) using the default config value:

`--web.listen-address=:9090`

In that case, Prometheus will not bind to ipv4 interface and is only available with ipv6. Many people do not want this, and should set default listener interface explicitly.

These files in `/etc/default/` are automatically read by the service units when starting up. It is not paradigmatic to modify the service unit, if there is a config file for the purpose.

Counterintuitively, it is not `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`, because this file only describes prometheus workloads not the system service configuration.