# How to configure a specific IP in prometheus yml configuration file?

Tags: linux, prometheus

I would like to run Prometheus with a specific IP address. By default, it is running on localhost. I don't see any such option in the  [prometheus configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

Comment: maybe you should expand your question (but I don't have an answer; I'm also struggling with making prometheus load from a specific path, not root). The prometheus documentation is quite bad

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the command line option for configuring your listen address

```
./prometheus --web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:9090"
```

Comment: thanks. But is there any way to give it in the promethues yml config file?

Comment: from [an old google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prometheus-users/vX5XAgfGjp4/CDXK-ueTAAAJ): _"No, the configuration file is for options that can change dynamically.  Changing the listen address is not possible on the fly."_

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the packages for Debian-based systems, you can persistently modify the command line argument `--web.listen-address` in `/etc/default/prometheus` (and same for /etc/default/prometheus-node-exporter).

You can change both the address to be bound (e.g. blank (`0.0.0.0`) or `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.xx.xx`) and the port number (e.g. `9090`) here (e.g. `:9090` or `127.0.0.1:9090`).

It will look like:

```
# Set the command-line arguments to pass to the server.
ARGS="--web.listen-address=127.0.0.1:9090"
```

(Don't forget to `systemctl restart prometheus prometheus-node-exporter` afterward.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414593/configure-prometheus-to-use-non-default-port