# Unable to start prometheus even after using a different port

Tags: prometheus

my prometheus configuration looks like below

```
cat /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml |grep targets
    - targets:
    - targets: ['localhost:10090']
```

Unfortunately, **/var/log/messages** reports errors as like below

```
Apr  6 17:04:57 ip-172-31-14-101 prometheus: level=error ts=2020-04-06T07:04:57.638Z caller=main.go:747 err="error starting web server: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9090: bind: address already in use"
Apr  6 17:04:57 ip-172-31-14-101 systemd: prometheus.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr  6 17:04:57 ip-172-31-14-101 systemd: Unit prometheus.service entered failed state.
Apr  6 17:04:57 ip-172-31-14-101 systemd: prometheus.service failed.
```

Port 9090 is used by Chef hence I am using port 10090. Is there any default configuration I need to update? Missing something?

**Host OS is Amazon Linux 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` specification is not where to listen, it is where to collect metrics from.

What you want to modify is the listen address. The `man` page lists the command line option `--web.listen-address="0.0.0.0:9090"`, you could either change the command line or modify the config file appropriately.

Oh, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672748/), someone has already answered a similar question with a better answer. The config file change suggested is:

```
# Set the command-line arguments to pass to the server.
ARGS="--web.listen-address=localhost:10090"
```

I did a google search for `prometheus listen port config` and found that answer. You should search before you ask, I should search before I answer.