# Prometheus always starts with default configs

Tags: prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and YAML, and am getting started with setting up Prometheus on one of the linux server with say IP address: XXX

This is my YAML file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["XXXX:9092"]
```

As you can see, I am trying to start prometheus on IP XXX and not "localhost" and also port is 9092.

But in the logs I am always seeing this line:
`level=info component=web msg="Listening on" address=0.0.0.0:9090`

What am I missing? If my YAML configuration wrong?

I have tried with another config file, like the following:

```
 global:
   scrape_interval: 10s
 scrape_configs:
   - job_name: prometheus
     static_configs:
       - targets:
          - XXX:9092
```

I always get the same INFO that prometheus is listening on `0.0.0.0:9090`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you've done is define a *external* server with port 9092 for Prometheus to scrape *from itself*.

You don't set Prometheus bind address / server port from scrape_configs. And it should collect metrics from itself, by default.

To change Prometheus http port, and make it externally accessible (`localhost` doesn't matter, as the logs say, it's already bound to all external interfaces, including "IP XXX") see [Configure Prometheus to use non-default port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47414593/2308683)

Aside: port 9092 is the default of Apache Kafka, which doesn't expose a endpoint that can be scraped for metrics